# Does sculpting add polygons?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

i'm trying to morph between a regular sphere and a 'head', but i want to ask, when i sculpt the sphere there are added polygons? i'm trying to use the modifiers Shrinkwrap but it does seems to not work perfectly.

Can someone help me with this? or even suggest me a better option to morph between two shapes (it's a sphere and a literal sphere with face with simple features)

Comment: Do you want to animate between a sphere and a face? Or just sculpt a sphere into a face?

Comment: Sculpting does not add polygons unless you use Dyntopo.

Comment: @gandalf3 i need to morph between a sphere that 'grows' eyes and mouth (no literal eyes, just the 'holes' from the original geometry) and if its possible animate it with shape keys or a simple facial rig to close/open eyes and mouth.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-zH5RSdi7A&index=67&list=PL3GeP3YLZn5hCYXZp2yACPZWn-wQik6fD).